# Filter array of objects based on array input

Tags: javascript, filter

I have an `Array` of `Objects`.

Each array of Objects contains an array `items` and each item in this array is an Object containing an array `category`:

```
var obj = [
  // first object
  {
    label: 'Label 1',
    // first items
    items: [
      {
        id: 1,
        itemName: 'Item Name 1',
        img: 'imgs/path-to1.jpeg',
        sizes: [],
        colors: [],
        // first category
        category: [
          'I',
          'E',
          'M'
        ],
        defaultChoices: {}
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        itemName: 'Item Name 2',
        img: 'imgs/path-to2.jpeg',
        sizes: [],
        colors: [],
        // second category
        category: [
          'I',
          'E'
        ],
        defaultChoices: {}
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        itemName: 'Item Name 3',
        img: 'imgs/path-to3.jpeg',
        sizes: [],
        colors: [],
        // third category
        category: [
          'I'
        ],
        defaultChoices: {}
      },
    ]
  },
  // second object
  {
    label: 'Label 2',
    // second items
    items: [
      {
        id: 7,
        itemName: 'Item Name 7',
        img: 'imgs/path-to7.jpeg',
        sizes: [],
        colors: [],
        // fourth category
        category: [
          'I',
          'M'
        ],
        defaultChoices: {}
      },
      ...
```

just to make the things clearer, a typical direct access to `category` would be performed this way: `obj[0].items[0].category`.

From the frontend of the app, the user, based on her choices, can send to the application one of the following arrays:

- `['I']`;
- `['E']`;
- `['M']`;
- `['I','E']`;
- `['I','M']`;
- `['E','M']`;
- `['I','E','M']`;
- ...;

Then, *the application should return the obj array filtered*: if, for example, the user sent `['I']`, the array should contain any objects where category contains 'I'. If the user sent `['E','M']`, the array should contain any object where category contains `['E','M']` (no matter if category is `['E','M','I']`), and so on.

I red a lot of docs about the JS `filter` function but I was not able to develop one function that, given the user array, can return a new array as result of filtering `obj`. I found dozen of docs with non-real-life examples like this one:

```
var hs = [
    {name: 'Batman', franchise: 'DC'},
    {name: 'Ironman', franchise: 'Marvel'}
];

var marvels =  heroes.filter(function(h) {
    return hs.franchise == 'Marvel';
});

Any help is appreciated.
```

[UPDATE] I add a more realistic data sample, sorry for not providing it before: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sdRx6sQ-cnRXJ8YCe4QH2Sy5fa5mopYW

Comment: how should the result look like? do you want the objects with only nested wanted categories? mutated or a new one?

Comment: @NinaScholz: the resulting array obj must have the current structure, but if one category in one object doesn't match the user preferences, it should be removed from items (for example, if the user sends ['M'], the item with id=2 must be removed). I prefer a new array, anyway.

Comment: obj.map(obj => obj.items.filter(item => data.every(c => item.category.includes(c))));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code iterates through all Objects and items and creates a new Object with only items that have the specified Categories. A more detailed description of the the Code is in the Comments:

```js
// function where you enter the Objects and the Categories you want to filter
function getFilterObjectItems(objs, categories){
  // Filtered Objects
  return objs.map(function(obj) {
    // Creates a new Item
    var newObject = {label: obj.label, items:[]};
    //iterate through all items in an Object looking for items with matching Category
    obj.items.forEach(function(item){
      // if one category entry matches add item to new Object
      //  the "some" function returns "true" or "false" if one item matches the critieria
      if(item && item.category && item.category.some && item.category.some(cat => searchedCAT.indexOf(cat)>-1)){
        // the original item will be added to the new item ist
        newObject.items.push(item);
      }
    });
    return newObject;
  })
  // filters all New Objects that don't have items
  .filter(newObject => newObject.items.length>0);
}


// DATA from the Question
var obj = [
  // first object
  {
    label: 'Label 1',
    // first items
    items: [
      {
        id: 1,
        itemName: 'Item Name 1',
        img: 'imgs/path-to1.jpeg',
        sizes: [],
        colors: [],
        // first category
        category: [
          'I',
          'E',
          'M'
        ],
        defaultChoices: {}
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        itemName: 'Item Name 2',
        img: 'imgs/path-to2.jpeg',
        sizes: [],
        colors: [],
        // second category
        category: [
          'I',
          'E'
        ],
        defaultChoices: {}
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        itemName: 'Item Name 3',
        img: 'imgs/path-to3.jpeg',
        sizes: [],
        colors: [],
        // third category
        category: [
          'I'
        ],
        defaultChoices: {}
      },
    ]
  },]

// search Categories
var searchedCAT = ['I'];


// Calling the Function
console.info(getFilterObjectItems(obj, searchedCAT));
```

Comment: While your result very much resembles what I'm looking for, for some reason I get: TypeError: item.category is undefined when I run it in Firefox and Cannot read property 'some' of undefined if I test at repl.it Moreover, if you look for 'I', the function is not returning the item with id=3

Comment: @Guest thi i=§ was a minor error didn't check for -1. is found now. the some error I will check, right away on ff.

Comment: @Guest Are you sure the data is "save"? I added some check for `item` and `item.category`, maybe some items don't have category, with the provided data it work also on FireFox

Comment: Any items have category   :-)   I tried with your data and it works, I tried with mine and it doesn't. To avoid my boss killing me, I anonimize the real data and I post it as soon as possible.

Comment: @Guest even, now with the check, it doesn't work? No error should come since I'm even checking if the `some` function exists. :-D

Comment: This is more realistic data sample: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sdRx6sQ-cnRXJ8YCe4QH2Sy5fa5mopYW (it looks very similar to the code you tested, I don't understand at the moment why it doesn't work, I'm gonna try a diff)

Comment: @guest i just tried your data, and with my code it works no error and returns 5 Elements for `var searchedCAT = ['I']` .

Comment: @guest the problem is that item `L3 Item Name 17` in `Label 3` doesn't have a category

Comment: the check in the if-statement `item && item.category && item.category.some` prevents the error. _(and is normally best practices, but not alway done in "fast", demo code)_

Comment: you found an error in our middleware! You won nothing, but you worried a couple of ugly ugly guys working at the server side of the application   :-)

Comment: Glad to help, AND please remember, also ugly guys need/want/like kind words. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to filter by category, which the number of `object` in the array is remained unchanged(even all items in that object are filter out and there is no item in the object), then it should be what you want:

```
var obj = [ // I removed some unnecessary params to make it clear, which shouldn't affect any
  {
    label: 'Label 1',
    items: [
      {
        id: 1,
        category: ['I', 'E', 'M'],
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        category: ['I', 'E'],
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        category: ['I'],
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'Label 2',
    items: [
      {
        id: 7,
        category: ['I', 'M'],
      },
    ]}
]


function filterByCategory(obj, categories) {
  return obj.map( o => ({
    ...o, // copy everything(i.e. label, items)
    items: o.items.filter(item => // modify items in the obj
       categories.some(c => item.category && item.category.includes(c)) // keep item if some categories are in item
    )
  }))
}
const filteredObj = filterByCategory(obj, ['I', 'E'])
console.log(filteredObj)
```

If you want to further filter out the object that there is no item, you can add
`.filter(o => o.items.length)` at the end of `filterByCategory`.

**Live Example:**

```js
var data = [ { label: 'Label 1', items: [{ id: 1, itemName: 'Item Name 1', img: 'imgs/path-to1.jpeg', sizes: [], colors: [], category: [ 'I', 'E', 'M' ], defaultChoices: {} }, { id: 2, itemName: 'Item Name 2', img: 'imgs/path-to2.jpeg', sizes: [], colors: [], category: [ 'I', 'E' ], defaultChoices: {} }, { id: 3, itemName: 'Item Name 3', img: 'imgs/path-to3.jpeg', sizes: [], colors: [], category: [ 'I' ], defaultChoices: {} }, ] }, { label: 'Label 2', items: [{ id: 7, itemName: 'Item Name 7', img: 'imgs/path-to7.jpeg', sizes: [], colors: [], category: [ 'I', 'M' ], defaultChoices: {} }] } ]; 

function filterByCategory(data, category) {
  return data.map(obj => {
    return { ...obj,
      "items": obj.items.filter(item =>
        category.some(value => item.category && item.category.includes(value))
      )
    };
  });
}

console.log(filterByCategory(data, ['E', 'M']));
```

Comment: Can you provide 2 usage examples?

Comment: This returns: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined at categories.every.c" (I must say, I tried something similar a couple of hours ago and got the same error)

Comment: If you still get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined ", then i think some of your items are undefined. In that case, do you want to remove all of them when filtering?

Comment: most probably OP passed an array to the method, thats why ended up with `TypeError`

Comment: Oh...should be category. Some items no category, which is undefined, not []?

Comment: "TypeError: item.category is undefined"

Comment: Try to add categories.every(c => item.category && item.category.includes(c))

Comment: @NCM: there can't be empty cateogory arrays. When you return an array, you must remove the item where category doesn't match the user preferences

Comment: This is not the expected result: you pass 'E' and 'M' and you should return any object that contains 'E' || 'M' while maybe you're returning 'E'&&'M'. Oh! Have you tried this in a regular browser? Here I get: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined"

Comment: Sorry, I read the question wrongly. Change every to some then. And for the 'includes' of undefined" , which mean your category is undefined. Please change to something like `categories.some(c => item.category && item.category.includes(c))`

Comment: btw.: I like your usage of the spread operator, nice twist. I had forgotten how good it is.

Answer (score 2):

```
const UserChoice = ['E', 'X'];
const filtered = obj.filter(o => {
  const filteredItems = o.items.filter(item =>
    item.category.map(c => UserChoice.includes(c)).includes(true)
  );
  if (filteredItems.length > 0) {
    o.items = filteredItems;
    return o;
  }
});
```

"filtered" will have your filtered obj

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses four Array methods to filter the `obj` array: `.filter`, `.some`, `.every`, and `.includes`.

```js
// __Simplified version of the 'obj' array__
var obj = [
  {
    label: '1',
    items: [
      {id:1, category:['I','E','M']},
      {id:2, category:['I','E'] },
      {id:3, category:['I']}
    ]
  },
  {
    label: '2',
    items: [
      { id:7, category: ['I','M']}
    ]
  }
];


// __The filter function__
// (Takes an array of user input, and filters the global
//   `obj` array to return a new array)
function filterObj(inputArray){ 
  const filtered = obj.filter( object => // Keep the object if...
    object.items.some( item => // some item in the object passes this test:
      inputArray.every( value => // For every value in the input array...
        item.category.includes(value) // the item's 'category' array includes value
      )
    )
  );
  return filtered;
}

// __Testing function__
// (Calls `filterObj` on a test array and logs the results)
function test(input){
  console.log(`Testing this input: ${ input }`);
  console.log("Obects having `some` item where `every` value in the input array is `included`:");
  filterObj(input).forEach( matchingObject => { console.log(matchingObject.label); });
  console.log("");
}

// __Tests__
test(['I','M']);
test(['I','E']);
```

(Note: The output is according to the OP's original specification that 
"if, for example, the user sent ['I'], the array **should contain any objects where** category contains 'I' ")